How to properly introspect Keycloak access tokens using the internal Docker URL?
This code successfully introspects a Keycloak access token using Python Keycloak and FastAPI:
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url="https://example.com/auth/",
    realm_name="abc",
    client_id="myclient",
    client_secret_key="secret",
    verify=False,
)
header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
token = header.split()[1]
token_info = keycloak_openid.introspect(token)
print(token_info)

However, when replacing the server URL with http://keycloak:8080/auth/ (the internal address of the Keycloak container in my Docker Compose setup), I get this output: {'active': False}.
Here is my Docker Compose setup:
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2
    command: 
      - start
      - --import-realm
      - --features=hostname:v2
    volumes:
      - ./config/keycloak/imports:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    environment:
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-db/access-control-db
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KC_HOSTNAME=example.com
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true     
      - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
      - KC_PROXY_HEADERS=xforwarded
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db
    restart: always

  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: access-control-db
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - keycloak-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  keycloak-db-data:

I tried not providing the KC_HOSTNAME variable, but it had no effect.
How can I make my code work with http://keycloak:8080/auth/?

Are you running the code you show in a container?  I don't see it referenced in the Compose file anywhere, but it would need to be on the same Docker network for that host name to work.

They are indeed on the same network. Thanks.

Setting the KC_HOSTNAME variable to https://example.com/auth/ solved the issue due to an unclear reason.
Here is the entire specs for Keycloak on the docker-compose.yml file:
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2
    command: 
      - start
      - --import-realm
      - --features=hostname:v2
    volumes:
      - ./config/keycloak/imports:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    environment:
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://keycloak-db/access-control-db
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      - KC_HOSTNAME=https://example.com/auth/
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true     
      - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
      - KC_PROXY_HEADERS=xforwarded

